# Enabling OAUTH on WSO2 API Manager's built-in product endpoints such as /services/echo, /services/Version and /services/WorkflowCallbackService

Tags: wso2-api-manager, apache-synapse

The standard configuration of WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0 exposes a number of product services without enforcing authentication and authorisation controls through the usual OAuth token mechanism employed by WSO2.  These services (/services/echo, /services/Version and /services/WorkflowCallbackService) presents unauthenticated users with product and service information you would not generally want to provide.

Without requiring a bearer token, WSO2 would gladly return the Version information and WorkflowCallbackService WSDL upon request.

```
curl --insecure https://localhost:8243/services/Version

<ns:getVersionResponse xmlns:ns="http://version.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"><return>WSO2 API Manager-2.6.0</return></ns:getVersionResponse>
```

---

AND

---

```
curl --insecure https://localhost:8243/services/WorkflowCallbackService?wsdl

<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns="http://callback.workflow.apimgt.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" targetNamespace="http://callback.workflow.apimgt.carbon.wso2.org">
   <wsdl:documentation>WorkflowCallbackService</wsdl:documentation>
   <wsdl:types>
      <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://callback.workflow.apimgt.carbon.wso2.org">
         <xs:element name="resumeEvent">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="workflowReference" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="status" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="description" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="resumeEventResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
      </xs:schema>
   </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="resumeEventRequest">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:resumeEvent"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="resumeEventResponse">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:resumeEventResponse"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="WorkflowCallbackServicePortType">
      <wsdl:operation name="resumeEvent">
         <wsdl:input message="ns:resumeEventRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:resumeEvent"/>
         <wsdl:output message="ns:resumeEventResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:resumeEventResponse"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="WorkflowCallbackServiceSoap11Binding" type="ns:WorkflowCallbackServicePortType">
      <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="resumeEvent">
         <soap:operation soapAction="urn:resumeEvent" style="document"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:binding name="WorkflowCallbackServiceSoap12Binding" type="ns:WorkflowCallbackServicePortType">
      <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="resumeEvent">
         <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:resumeEvent" style="document"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:binding name="WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpBinding" type="ns:WorkflowCallbackServicePortType">
      <http:binding verb="POST"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="resumeEvent">
         <http:operation location="resumeEvent"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <mime:content type="text/xml" part="parameters"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <mime:content type="text/xml" part="parameters"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="WorkflowCallbackService">
      <wsdl:port name="WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:WorkflowCallbackServiceSoap11Binding">
         <soap:address location="https://DRACARYS:8243/services/WorkflowCallbackService.WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint"/>
      </wsdl:port>
      <wsdl:port name="WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:WorkflowCallbackServiceSoap11Binding">
         <soap:address location="http://DRACARYS:8280/services/WorkflowCallbackService.WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint"/>
      </wsdl:port>
      <wsdl:port name="WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:WorkflowCallbackServiceSoap12Binding">
         <soap12:address location="https://DRACARYS:8243/services/WorkflowCallbackService.WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint"/>
      </wsdl:port>
      <wsdl:port name="WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:WorkflowCallbackServiceSoap12Binding">
         <soap12:address location="http://DRACARYS:8280/services/WorkflowCallbackService.WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint"/>
      </wsdl:port>
      <wsdl:port name="WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpsEndpoint" binding="ns:WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpBinding">
         <http:address location="https://DRACARYS:8243/services/WorkflowCallbackService.WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpsEndpoint"/>
      </wsdl:port>
      <wsdl:port name="WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpBinding">
         <http:address location="http://DRACARYS:8280/services/WorkflowCallbackService.WorkflowCallbackServiceHttpEndpoint"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I am looking for a way to configure the endpoint (through mediation flow or service proxy) to return a 401 Unauthorized error to a request which doesn't include a valid OAuth token.

Comment: The above endpoints are not exposed as rest apis and they are web service endpoints. Usually, the echo and version endpoints are used in health check tasks. (to check whether the server is running). So, these endpoints are kept insecure.